# Ubuntu, g++, and Vulkan lib

Tags: g++, vulkan

I'm going through the [Vulkan Tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/).  I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and g++.  I'm not sure what the Vulkan lib is to enter with the `-l` flag (if that's my problem).  The first program of the tutorial, [here](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/base_code.cpp), runs with the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lglfw
```

However, the next program, [here](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/instance_creation.cpp), gives me the following error:

```
undefined reference to `vkCreateInstance'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score -1):

oops, the answer is at the beginning of the tutorial itself.

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lglfw -lvulkan
```

Comment: This would be a more useful answer if the information is pasted here instead of linking into a tutorial.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more what part of the linked tutorial helped you out. Added detailed explanation (what caused the error and) what solved it. Imagine this link could be broken some day, your answer would be useless then. Downvote until improved.